# Find surrounding elements in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to find the two elements surrounding an element in a list. I propose this code (it works) but I am pretty sure there is a way to do this in an easier way.

```
a = [4,5,6,8,9,15,16,18,54,60]
b = 24

i = 0
while i<len(a):
    if b > a[i-1] and b < a[i+1]:
        result = [a[i-1],a[i]]
        i = i+1
    else:
        i = i+1
```

It returns me:

```
>>> result
[18, 54]
```

Do you know the python function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. If you look the a array, you see that it is sorted, and that 18 is the first smallest and 54 is the first highest.

Comment: Well I don't think that's what I wanted...

Comment: Ever tried my reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use binary search. You need to find either first element that is greater than `b` or last element that is less than `b`. Say, we found index of first element that is greater with binary search at some index `j`. Then our answer is b[j - 1], b[j] and so on for other cases. This works in O(logN) time.

```
import bisect 
def find(a, b):
    n, j = len(a), bisect.bisect_left(a, b)
    if a[j] > b:
       return (None if j == 0 else a[j-1]), a[j] 
    else:
       return a[j], (None if j >= n - 1 else a[j + 1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [4,5,6,8,9,15,16,18,54,60]
    b = 24

    print find(a, 24)
    print find(a, 3)
    print find(a, 4)
    print find(a, 7)
    print find(a, 60)
```

Shorter approach:

```
import bisect 
def find(a, b):
    n, j = len(a), bisect.bisect_left(a, b)
    return ((None if j == 0 else a[j-1]), a[j]) if a[j] > b else (a[j], (None if j >= n - 1 else a[j + 1]))
```

**Important**: array should be in sorted order

Comment: It will probably work, but I'm looking for something shorter than what I did. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one instance where `b` is between two consecutive numbers, you can use `zip` and check paired elements:

```
a = [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 16, 18, 54, 60]
b = 24

for i, j in zip(a,a[1:]):
    if i < b < j:
        result = [i,j]
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this one-liner (Python 3.7):

```
import numpy as np

a = [4,5,6,8,9,15,16,18,54,60]
b = 24

surrounding_values = np.sort([b + i for i in sorted(np.subtract(a,b),key=lambda x: abs(x))[:2]])
```

This basically takes the first two values of the sorted differences between the values of the array (b) and the value (a).

Edit: This only works if the steps in array (a) are similar, which is not the case here.